# XSD 1.1 assert test containing single quote

Tags: xsd, assert, xsd-1.1, single-quotes

Anybody got an idea why the following won't work? The xsd is validated with Xerces

```xml
<xs:element name="myElement">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="myElementType">
        <xs:assert test="firstname = 'George' and lastName = 'Mc&apos;Falrland'" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The error hits when i use the single quote `&apos;` entity...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is related to XPath string literals, as XSD 1.1 uses XPath 2.0 you can escape an apostrophe or quotes inside a string literal by writing the delimiter two times, so you can use:

```
<xs:assert test="firstname = 'George' and lastName = 'Mc''Falrland'" />
```

For more info you can use [XPath 2.0 specs, section *Literals*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-literals):

> **If the literal is delimited by apostrophes, two adjacent apostrophes
>   within the literal are interpreted as a single apostrophe**. Similarly,
>   if the literal is delimited by quotation marks, two adjacent quotation
>   marks within the literal are interpreted as one quotation mark.

Comment: Thank you. That's a lot better than what i did
"firstname = &quot;George&quot; and lastName = 'Mc&apos;Falrland'"

Comment: You are welcome, if this is useful and solves your problem you must accept the answer (check the tick, already done) and upvote the answer click the upper gray triangle, thanks in advance.